# How do i use this unicode character properly?

Tags: html, unicode, character

If i tyoe correct unicode in html encoded version than it just shows blank or empty box. `&#11801;`, its the code i want to use. Ive tried setting utf8 and utf 16 in meta tag but it didnt work.

Is there a limit to what characters you cna use in html.

Comment: What server do you use to serve your documents? Is it properly configured (does it send proper HTTP headers to indicate the encoding of documents)? And what font do you use in your document? No all fonts support the whole Unicode - does your font contain the required glyph(s)?

Comment: No server just jsfiddle for now, im setting encoding using meta tag, im using default font, does it?

Comment: I don't know. And I actually cannot know - it's **your browser's** default font, I don't know which one it is.

Comment: Actually, you can check it e.g. here: https://codepoints.net/U+2E19 - my browser's default font does not support this "palm branch" character.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a limit to what characters you cna use in html.

Not intrinsically, but computers don't generally shipped with fonts that have glyphs for *every* possible character. U+2E19 Palm Branch is a relatively new addition to Unicode (version 5.1) and not many people use it, so font support is not widespread.

If you have a font that includes it, you could embed that using a CSS `@font-face` rule to ensure browsers can render it. Otherwise, an image (or SVG) would probably be a simpler way to include the shape.

Comment: so what characters are supported widely, say ie9+ to all.

Comment: You can use sites like [fileformat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e19/fontsupport.htm) to see what fonts support a particular character.